# Why is my Windows laptop reseeting file permission when I write to a file on a drive mapped to my macbook across same LAN?

Tags: windows, networking, mac, macbook, file-permissions

When my Windows laptop writes to a file in a drive mapped to my macbook, on the same LAN, it changes the permission of the file
from "-rwxrwxrwx" to "-rw-------" which means I must go to the macbook to change the permission back to "-rwxrwxrwx" before my macos app (Xcode) can access the file.

UPDATE...
The files are on the Mac with permission rwxrwxrwx (ie. sudo chmod -rwx *).  The Windows laptop, across Ethernet LAN, opens a file that is on the Mac, changes it, writes the file back to Mac, but then changes the file's permission to "rw-------" so that I then must use chmod on the Mac to change the permission back to rwxrwxrwx.

Happens every time I update any of my Mac data files from my Windows laptop.

SPECIFICS...
Mac files are .swift source code.
Files edited by Visual Studio on Windows.

Comment: Is the windows laptop responsible for the file permisstions on the Macbook, or is it the Macbook that is responsible for the file permissions on the Macbook?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "responsible for file permissions." Please see UPDATE in question